# I am trying to insert a edit text box onto a tab

Tags: java, android, tabs

I am working on a android project and I have my four tabs.  On one of the tabs, I am trying to insert an edit field box.  ANy clues on how to do that?

Here is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="year of car" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is another tab" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is a third tab" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is a fourth tab" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and here is my .java file:

```
package com.example.gasfillup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class GasFillup extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Car Info").setContent(R.id.textview1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Fillup Info").setContent(R.id.textview2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Gas Milage").setContent(R.id.textview3));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4").setIndicator("Stats").setContent(R.id.textview4));       
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }
}
```

Any Ideas or help is much appreciated!!

ironmantis7x

Comment: So are you trying to get an edit box *on the tab*, or within the content of the tab?

Comment: within the content of the tab ... sorry I should have been more clear. @Stargazer712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your  with a  ... so, framelayout, linearlayout, textview, edittext then close the linearlayout.

Well, let me edit that ... create a separate XML file to hold the entire view you want on the tab and then set it with R.layout.tab1 rather than setting tab1 to the textview.

Comment: Not understanding your reply.  Can you give me an example??

Comment: That worked!!!  I will read more on containers in java and try out some more stuff!!

Comment: Show some love man.  Throw me the upvote and the check mark ;)  It help my reputation and it shows other people you'll acknowledge their help.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill Mote said, you need to wrap the content of the tab within some sort of container. Here's an example using a simple LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="year of car" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is another tab" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is a third tab" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panel4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="this is a fourth tab" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/myeditfield"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Then change your code behind to:

```
....
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4").setIndicator("Stats").setContent(R.id.panel4));
....
```

Realistically, this is how you should do all of the tabs (so that you can have more than just text), but you get the idea.

Comment: OK -- I must me a real idiot ... I tried to replicate the same structure for the other tabs and it is not working in the emulator ... what am I doing wrong??

Comment: can you give me a hand on this??  I am a newbie to Java and Android and XML.

Comment: I am now getting garbage on the screen when I try to switch tabs (like text is overwriting from the other tab views).  Any ideas??

Comment: I found the fix ... the android:singleLine="true" goes into the EditText part of the code.